# Best practice of using unittest kind asserts (like assertNotIn) in standalone pytest tests?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, python-unittest

In standalone `pytest` test cases I would like to use assertions like `unittest.TestCase.assertNotIn` (and [`unittest`s other asserts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#assert-methods)) without any dependency on the `uniittest` module. Is best practice to use libraries like [python-assert](https://github.com/srittau/python-asserts)?

Comment: In what way dependency on an external library (python-assert) is better that dependency on a stdlib module (unittest)?

Comment: Some pytest features which I want to use are not compatible with unittest.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best practice is using the language `assert` statement, which yields the `unittest`'s `assert*` methods unnecessary. Compare

```
self.assertNotIn(a, b, 'element a is not found in sequence b')
```

with

```
assert a not in b, 'element a is not found in sequence b'
```

The latter is much more pythonic. It is also one of the key features that `pytest` names in the [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/index.html):

> Detailed info on failing assert statements (no need to remember `self.assert*` names)

Should you be missing any `unittest` methods, `pytest` aims to provide replacements for them:

```
with self.assertRaises(Exception):
    spam()
```

becomes

```
with pytest.raises(Exception):
    spam()
```

,

```
self.assertAlmostEqual(a, b)
```

becomes

```
assert a == pytest.approx(b)
```

etc.